# Getting error "Could not load oplib `nqp_dyncall_ops'" + traceback when executing raku one liner

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, raku, traceback, rakudo

I have a rakudo instance that will do nothing other than respond with "Could not load oplib 'nqp_dyncall_ops'".

Using the REPL:

```
perl6

Could not load oplib 'nqp_dyncall_ops

exit

Unable to load setting CORE; maybe it is missing a YOU_ARE_HERE?
```

when executing a script it gives me a trackback as well

```
perl6 -e "say 22"

Could not load oplib `nqp_dyncall_ops' current instr.: '' pc 6006 (src/gen/perl6-moduleloader.pir:2605) (gen/parrot/ModuleLoader.nqp:349) . . . called from Sub 'MAIN' pc 345 (src/gen/perl6.pir:128) (gen/parrot/main.nqp:45) called from Sub '' pc 317 (src/gen/perl6.pir:112) (gen/parrot/main.nqp:35) called from Sub '' pc 1054 (src/gen/perl6.pir:378) (gen/parrot/main.nqp:58)
```

Running this on Ubuntu (WSL Windows Subsystem for Linux)

apt-get install shows I have the latest version

```
apt-get install perl6 Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done Note, selecting 'rakudo' instead of 'perl6' rakudo is already the newest version. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 242 not upgraded.
```

Running on the win32 subsystem on the same machine runs ok

```
F:>raku

To exit type 'exit' or '^Z'

2 2 ^Z

F:>perl6 -e "say 2" 2
```

Comment: The output references parrot multiple times, which means the perl6 that was installed with apt-get is far too old to be useful.

Comment: ❶ I haven't seen anything as borked as that in the 9 years I've been answering P6/Raku Qs here (since 2013). ❷ As ugexe notes, the error mentions Parrot. Parrot was discontinued as a Rakudo target 8 years ago. ❸ ["Could not load oplib"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Could+not+load+oplib%22) has 7 results. 6 report problems in 2012 or earlier. The only other one is... your SO. ❹ I've no idea what's going on but I don't think we're going to be able to sort it out here on SO. Please ask on [`#moarvm` IRC channel](https://kiwiirc.com/nextclient/irc.libera.chat/#moarvm).

Comment: ❺ ["nqp_dyncall_ops"](https://www.google.com/search?q=nqp_dyncall_ops) claims 30 odd results. Of particular note are ❻ jdn06's 2015-01-07 archlinux comment ["I tried on another computer and it worked. I don't know what happened the previous time, but anyway everything seems ok."](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rakudo#comment-474353) 5 days after saying "I have a problem when I try to build rakudo-2014.12-1 ... could not find library `nqp_dyncall_ops'"; ❼ It's almost certainly a red herring, but there's also 2012 ["fails ... on windows"](https://logs.liz.nl/perl6/2012-06-24.html#17:17).

Comment: ❽ A final thought: What are the sources of the `apt-get` you're using in WSL? Who curates those sources? Perhaps it's M$ and/or they're utter crap at curation?

Comment: Yah, sounds like it is an issue with an aging ubuntu/dpkging system. I'll investigate.
Yikes!!!
uname -v
#1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014

Comment: Yikes indeed. Or "Wow", to quote jnthn in [the log of today's chat on the IRC `#moarvm` channel about this SO](https://irclogs.raku.org/moarvm/2022-03-24.html). Please let us know here on SO and/or the IRC channel about any observations or conclusions you have about how best to view WSL and/or the sources of `apt-get` on WSL. Thank you for investigating.

Comment: Whoever is curating Rakudo's packaging relative to WSL may argue they didn't realize their Rakudo package was obsolete and need evidence to even consider fixing it. If so: ❶ [Rakudo support for Parrot as a back-end was "officially" suspended](http://pmthium.com/2015/02/suspending-rakudo-parrot/) in February 2015, 7 years ago, not 8 as I miscalculated/wrote in an earlier comment. ❷ In 20201 [Parrot itself was "officially" pronounced "Inactive"](https://web.archive.org/web/20210914170902/http://www.parrot.org/news/inactive-parrot) (avoiding a gratuitous/obvious Monty Python reference) in 2021.